# diferentes paginaciones laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paginación

Hola tengo un div donde llegan un listado de recetas paginadas, hasta ahi esta funcionando correctamente con su paginacion y los links funcionan correctamente.

Ahora agregue una barra de busqueda que funciona y trae los resultados paginados, pero los links de la paginacion que trae hacen que se muestre la segunda pagina de los items traidos originalmente osea sin el filtro de busqueda.

La funcion que trae todos los libros al cargar la pagina:

```php
function index(Request $request)
    {
      $libros = DB::table('booksindex')->paginate(9);

      if($request->ajax()){
          return response()->json(view('book',compact('libros'))->render());
      }
      return view('libros', ["libros" => $libros]);
    }
```

La funcion que trae los libros filtrados:

```php
function search(Request $request){
     if($request->ajax()){
        $titulo = $request->titulo;
        $libros = Libros::where('title','like','%'.$titulo.'%')->paginate(9);
        return response()->json(view('book',compact('libros'))->render());  
     }
}
```

funcion que ejecuta el search:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submitsearch', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var titulo = $('#search').val().trim();
        var csrf = $('#csrf').val();
        var route = "/search";
        $.ajax({
            url: route,
            data: {
                _token: csrf,
                titulo: titulo,
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // console.log(data);
                $('#insert').html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Usas alguna funcion de JS?

Comment: acabo de agregar la funcion que ejecuta la busqueda

Answer (score 0):

Los links de paginación se dibujan cuando blade renderea toda la tabla, así que tú tendrías que modificarlos cuando filtres via ajax (a menos que quieras refrescar la página que no creo...)

En tu caso, suponiendo que la paginación estuviera dentro de un contenedor `<ul class="pager">` podrías hacer (luego de success):

```
let contenedor = document.querySelector('ul.pager'),
    linkNodes = contenedor.querySelectorAll('a'),
    linkArray = Array.from(linkNodes);
```

Y finalmente

```
linkArray.forEach(link => { 
  let url=new URL(link.href);

  url.searchParams.set('titulo','wat'); 

  link.href=url.href;
});
```

Nótese que este forEach instancia un constructor de [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), cuyo atributo [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) modifico tratándolo como objeto. Perfectamente podrías sólo manipular el atributo href del link como string, pero con este enfoque tienes control sobre el query string y no necesitas verificar los filtros previamente existentes.